# MS Azure ASP pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, azure-web-app-service

We have ASP.Net MVC Application and deployed on Azure as Cloud Services.

The application  also have some legacy code written in Classic ASP.

Our system works on Classic Mode only.

We need to use multiple instance for Web Role.

We decided to move to outproc cache with Redis Cache.  Our problem how to use Redis Cache Session Management with Legacy System written in ASP.

Answer (score 0):

> Our problem how to use Redis Cache Session Management with Legacy System written in ASP.

If I understand you correctly, you want to use custom session-state mode with the Redis in your MVC WebForm application.

AFAIK, you could leverage the [Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider/) package as your custom session state provider for redis cache. And your session state provider configuration would look like as follows:

```html
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
    <providers>
        <add type = "Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
             name = "MySessionStateStore" 
             connectionString = "{your-valid-StackExchange.Redis-connection-string}"/>
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

For more details about the configurations, you could follow [here](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Configuration).

Moreover, you could follow [Announcing ASP.NET Session State Provider for Redis Preview Release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release/) and [ASP.NET Session State Management with Redis (Local Server Farm Testing)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040453/ASP-NET-Session-State-Management-with-Redis-Local).

Comment: How ASP will use Redis Cache session?

Comment: AFAIK, the  Active Server Pages (ASP) would store session data in memory. I just found a documentation talking about storing the session data to SQL Server, you could follow [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx).

Comment: SQL Server will slow down performance of system. That is why we need to use Distributed Session with Redis Cache.